# Como verificar se arquivo existe no diretório da aplicação no armazenamento interno?

Tags: android

Estou tentando verificar se um arquivo existe no diretório da aplicação no armazenamento interno com o código abaixo

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/meu_diretorio/arquivo";
    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "O arquivo não existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "O arquivo existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Estou utilizando as permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

No entanto não está funcionando. Como devo proceder com essa verificação?

Comment: o `meu_diretório` tem acento mesmo ou só exemplo?

Comment: Era só um exemplo.

Comment: Está dando algum erro na aplicação?! Você concedeu permissão de leitura ou escrita?

Comment: Estou utilizando as permissões que incluí na pergunta. Não está dando nenhum erro.

Comment: Em vez de `getPath()` você tentou usar `getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: Não deu certo também!

Comment: Deixa eu entender! Existe o arquivo, mas sua aplicação não reconhece certo?! Você chegou a debugar e ver se está pegando o caminho corretamente?!

Comment: O caminho que é mostrado no path é `storage/emulated/0/` mas o correto deveria ser o `data/br.com.minhaaplicacao/meu_diretorio/arquivo` ou eu estou confundindo tudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que está a usar é para aceder ao armazenamento **externo**.

Se quer obter o caminho para a raiz do armazenamento **interno** deve usar [File getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).
Para obter o caminho completo para um arquivo `name`, guardado no armazenamento **interno**, use [File getFileStreamPath(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String))

**Notas:**

- Os métodos indicados são da classe Context(Activity é um Context).
- Não são necessárias quaisquer permissões para ler/escrever no directório/arquivo.
- Os arquivos deverão ter sidos escritos recorrendo a um FileOutputStream obtido pelo método [FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)).
- Veja [Como usar armazenamento interno](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema apresentado no tópico.